# Find all analytic functions $f: E \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $z=(f(z))^n$ for all $z \in E$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $E=\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z: z \leq 0\}$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Find all analytic functions $f: E \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $z=(f(z))^n$ for all $z \in E$.

I'm a bit thrown as to where to start for this one. I believe I want to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to determine analyticity but coming up with the actual functions or a general form is a bit mystifying.

Comment: Hint: If $(f(z))^n = z$, then $f$ is the inverse of the map $x \to x^n$, i.e. the inverse of the $n$-th power operation. Any idea what that might be?

Comment: If in doubt, take logs.

Comment: So our $f$ should be of the form $\sqrt[n]{z}$? I'm not sure how this generalizes to all analytic functions that satisfy this...

Answer (score 4):

Let $R$ denote the set of functions in question. Note that if $f \in R$ then $f(z) \neq 0 $ for all $z$ (why?).

First we need to show that $R$ is not empty. Here we use logs, let
$f(z) = e^{{1 \over n} \log z}$, and note that $f^n(z) = z$.

Next we need to characterise **all** functions in $R$.

Suppose $z\neq 0$ and note that $z^n = w^n$ **iff** $z=w e^{{1 \over n} 2 \pi k i }$ for some $k$.

Now suppose $f,g \in R$. Then $f(z)^n = g(z)^n$ for $z \in E$ and so there
is some $k_z$ such that $f(z)=g(z) e^{{1 \over n} 2 \pi k_z i }$. Since
$f,g$ are non zero and analytic, it follows that $k_z=K$ for some $K$ and so
$f(z)=g(z) e^{{1 \over n} 2 \pi K i }$ for all $x \in E$ (since $E$ is connected).

Comment: You have to mention connectedness.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Good point. (For some reason your comment reminded me of an episode of an old BBC comedy called Fawlty Towers with the line "don't mention the war".)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not completely follow.

Comment: @az89: I can help with that, but you need to tell me where you are having difficulty.

Comment: In two places. When you assert $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log{z}}$. That makes some sense to me but something doesn't feel rigorous. Also, when you state $z^n=w^n$ iff ... That section I find confusion.
Also, what is $k_z$?

Comment: $R$ denotes all the functions $f:E \to \mathbb{C}$ that satisfy the condition. Note that $\log$ (the principal branch) is analytic on $E$. Then the function $f(z) = e^{{1 \over n} \log z}$ is analytic and $f(z)^n = e^{ \log z} = z$, hence this particular $f$ lies in $R$, so $R$ is not empty. This is completely rigorous.

Comment: Regarding the second confusion, we can write $z=r_z e^{i \phi_z}$ and similarly $w=r_w e^{i \phi_w}$ and so $z^n = w^n$ **iff** $r_z = r_w$ and $\phi_z-\phi_w$ is a multiple of ${1 \over n} 2 \pi$. This is a standard property of complex numbers.

Comment: For the third part, for a fixed $z$ there is some integer $k_z$ such that $f(z)=g(z) e^{{1 \over n} 2 \pi k_z i }$ (this follows from the previous comment). Since $f,g$ are analytic on the connected set $E$, we must have that $k_z$ is actually a constant.

Comment: @ZFR: Yes, because $E$ was conveniently chosen.

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution! I have tried to solve it by myself but all my approaches failed and I found your solution! +1

Comment: Hi! Could you please check my last topic about principal branch of $\sqrt{z-1}$? Please.

Comment: Elaborating the last step: Set $2\pi ih(z)= n\log (f(z)/g(z))$, where $\log$ is branch $C-\{z:z\le 0\}$ of the logarithm. Note that $h$ is continuous, $E$ is connected so $h(E)\subset \mathbb Z$ is connected. The only connected subsets of $\mathbb Z$ are singletons so $h(E)=\{K\}$ for some $K\in \mathbb Z$.